# Не могу использовать шаблон templateLayoutFactory в цикле

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Хочу пройти циклом по массиву меток `markers` и расставить эти метки на карте, используя шаблонизатор

```
ymaps.ready(init);

var myMap,
  markers = [{
    lat: 55.2049,
    lon: 30.1843,
    name: 'Имя 1',
    address: 'Адрес1',
    phone: '+322-32-11-22-33'
    hintContent: '<h3>This is Hint 1</h3>'
  },
  {
    lat: 54.80077688,
    lon: 32.00807933,
    name: 'Имя 2',
    address: 'Адрес 2',
    phone: '+322-32-55-66-111',
    hintContent: '<h3>This is Hint 2</h3>'
  }
  ];

function init() {
myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
  center: [55.18, 30.23],
  zoom: 5,
  controls: ['routeButtonControl'],
  behaviors: ['drag']
});

markers.forEach(function(m){
  var marker = new ymaps.Placemark(
  [m.lat, m.lon],
  {
    name: m.name,
    address: m.address,
    phone: m.phone,
    hintContent: m.hintContent 
  },
    { balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayoutClass } 
  );

  myMap.geoObjects.add(marker);

});  

var BalloonContentLayoutClass = 
ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
'<h3>{{ properties.name }}</h3>' + 
'<p>{{ properties.address }}</p>' +
'<p>{{ properties.phone }}</p>' +
); `
```

Метки ставятся, хинт виден, балуна нет. ((
Если цикл не пользовать, то статичные данные работают нормально

```
`var marker = new ymaps.Placemark(
[55.8, 37.6],
{
  name: 'Имя',
  address: 'Адрес',
  phone: '+7 (222) 555-44-33',
},
  { balloonContentLayout: MyBalloonContentLayoutClass }
);

myMap.geoObjects.add(marker);`
```

Печаль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная BalloonContentLayoutClass объявлена после использования:

```
balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayoutClass
```

.
.
.

```
var BalloonContentLayoutClass =
ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  '<h3>{{ properties.name }}</h3>' +
  '<p>{{ properties.address }}</p>' +
  '<p>{{ properties.phone }}</p>'
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/du0zjcyh/

Comment: Большое спасибо. Добавить пункт не могу - репутации нет ))

Comment: зы: а есть ли способ доставать такие ошибки из апи? чтобы  в консоль написалось например not defined и не тупить так больше?  Еще раз спасибо. ))

Comment: В процессе отладки часто полезно добавлять в подключение апи mode=debug http://jsfiddle.net/d87nr4bg/. Но в этом случае это не поможет, т.к. это больше похоже на логическую ошибку вашего кода. Это допустимая операция, она равнозначна balloonContentLayout: undefined, что равносильно options.unset('balloonContentLayout'). Что похоже на "я не хочу лаяут у контента балуна".